# Likelihood ratio tests vs. ANOVA for interactions in linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, likelihood-ratio

I am analyzing a longitudinal study where patients received either treatment 1, treatment 2 or no treatment (placebo) using linear mixed models (LMM) in R. I have a baseline measure that is related to changes in the outcome (significant 2-way interaction of predictor and time) and now would like to know if that baseline measure affects the 3 groups differently (3-way interaction of group, time, and predictor).

I am aware of three ways to conduct this test: An analysis of variance `anova()` or a likelihood ratio test, which can be conducted with `lmtest::lrtest()` or with `anova()` comparing the full model to a reduced model. My problem is the three ways provide very different results. Why is that so? And what would be the recommended approach to my question?

Here is some simulated data where the same problem occurs:

```
set.seed(99)

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(lmtest)

# Simulate data: 
# 210 subjects, divided into 3 groups, measured at 5 timepoints,
# a (baseline) predictor, and outcome symptoms. 
data <- data.frame(
  subject = as.factor(rep(1:210, each = 5)),
  group = as.factor(rep(c("placebo", "treatment1", "treatment2"), each = 70)),
  time = rep(c(0, 2, 3, 4, 6), times = 210),
  predictor = rep(rnorm(210, mean = 100, sd = 10), each = 5),
  symptoms = rnorm(210*5, mean = 100, sd = 10)
)

# Fit the standard linear mixed model (I tried with random slope, but that 
# produced convergence problems and thus only random intercept is used)
lmm <- lmer(symptoms ~ group*time*predictor + (1|subject), data)

# In my data, the time*predictor is significant, indicating that the predictor
# is related to symptom changes over time. I thus want to know if the 
# predictor behaves differently for the three groups.

# Reduced model without 3-way interaction 
lmm_red <- lmer(
  symptoms ~ group*time + group*predictor + time*predictor + (1|subject),
  data
  )

# Test 1: 
anova(lmm)

# Test 2: likelihood ratio test with lrtest()
lrtest(lmm_red, lmm)

# Test 3: likehood ratio test with anova()
anova(lmm_red, lmm)
```

I am aware that here have been previous posts on this topic, but they did not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lmer()` function uses the restricted maximum likelihood estimation by default. This is why you have a difference between `lrtest()` and `anova()`. If you fit with maximum likelihood, both give the same answer:

```
lmm <- 
    lmer(symptoms ~ group * time * predictor + (1 | subject), 
         data, REML = FALSE)
 
lmm_red <- 
    lmer(symptoms ~ (group + time + predictor)^2 + (1 | subject),
         data, REML = FALSE)

lrtest(lmm_red, lmm)

anova(lmm_red, lmm)
```

The call to `anova()` without a second argument uses an F-test with a Satterthwaite approximation for the denominator degrees of freedom. This also gives the same p-value here for the three-way interaction:

```
anova(lmm)
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed. By default, anova() refits models with ML, while lrtest() does not - creating huge differences in results. Thx a lot for answering!